# How can I avoid divs overlapping?

Tags: css

[image]

Hi, I will explain my problem...

The green box has variable height, it grows with its content.

I want the blue box docked to the bottom so...

`position: absolute;
bottom: 0;`

Problem is when the green box grows enough, it overlaps behind the blue one
Is there any way to avoid this without having to set a relative position to "blue"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must use static position for the blue box

Answer (score 0):

if there is no objects between this 2 you could set a bottom margin equal to blue divs height